# can't get a border around my wordpress widgets

Tags: wordpress, widget

At the moment, I'm building my own Wordpress Theme. Amongst others I have a problem with the widgets... i want them to have a border (CSS) but it wont work. I tried everything, from different paddings to different margins. I mean its just a border... can it really be that hard?!
URL: http://www.biggaa.de

Answer (score 1):

Search for this section in your CSS

```
#sidebar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px #CCC;
    background: black;
}
```

You need to change the line that says

```
border: 1px #CCC;
```

to

```
border: 1px solid #CCC;
```

Also, change to color to whatever you desire. Your widgets also use the CSS class "widget" so you could try doing this as well:

```
.widget {
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

I would recommend using [Chrome's Developer Tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools), or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, and inspect the element of the page (right-click then inspect element). This will allow you to focus in on areas of your website you want to change, without having to dig through all the CSS. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution did it. Im already using Firebug;)